# Insert a new row into a SQL SERVER CE 3.5 DB not working but doesn't show any error

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to do a simple In/out register with Visual Basic 2010.

I created a SQL server 3.5 CE database and in there a table with this structure:

[image]

There `Id` have the propriety `Identity  = true`

I got also this in a module

```
Dim Var_NombreDB As String = "OlgaDatabase.sdf"
Dim Var_ProveedorDB As String = "Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5"
Public Conexion_DB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=" & Var_ProveedorDB & ";Data Source=" & Var_NombreDB & ";")

Public SQL_string_conexion As String = ""

Public cmd_Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Public Dr_DataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
```

I'm opening the database connection correctly and I'm able to see the registers in a `DataGridView` without problems, but when I try to insert a new register just doesn't work, I got textBoxes (txt_) with the data and after fill them the  generated `CommandText` query is

```
INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (Tipo, SubTipo, Descripcion, Monto, Saldo, Fecha) 
VALUES ('1', '2', '3', 4, 24, GETDATE())
```

When I try it in the query syntax checker (in Server Explorer) the query is ok, and if I run it a new row is added to the table with the expected data.

But when I try to add new rows in running time even when it shows me the "ALL OK" MsgBox, no register is added to my table, This is the code inside my insert button

```
       cmd_Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd_Command.Connection = Conexion_DB

        SQL_string_conexion = "INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (Tipo, SubTipo, Descripcion, Monto, Saldo, Fecha) "

        SQL_string_conexion += "VALUES ('" _
            & txt_Tipo.Text & "', '" _
            & txt_Subtipo.Text & "', '" _
            & txt_Descripcion.Text & "', " _
            & txt_Monto.Text & ", " _
            & txt_Monto.Text + 20 & ", " _
            & "GETDATE()" _
            & ")"



        cmd_Command.CommandText = SQL_string_conexion

        Try
            cmd_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("All OK")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm thinking it have something to do with the `Id` column but I'm not sure.

Regards

Comment: Why are you using `OleDbConnection` etc? I'd recommend using the proper, native `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand`

Comment: Just because I'm using SQL Server for the fist time, adapting a code used for Access databases. Now that you pointed that, I tried to change every `OleDb.OleDbConnection` to `SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection`  and so on but now I can't even read the database. I always get an `System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled HResult=-2146233036` error with `Dim adp As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(SQLstr, Conexion_DB)` because of `Public Conexion_DB As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("Provider=" & Var_ProveedorDB & ";Data Source=" & Var_NombreDB & ";")`

Comment: Ok, I removed the "Provider" option and left the connection as `Public Conexion_DB As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" & Var_NombreDB & ";")` and now it runs fine an even shows me (in running time) the registers that I added, but when I get back to design/code the database doesn't have the new registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your bin/debug folder for a copy of the database file with data in it. (Duplicate of many answers here)

Workaround is to not include the sdf file in your project, or specify a full path to the .sdf file.

Comment: If I use that workaround how can I add that database to my project installer in the end? Thanks

Comment: Depends on the installer, but the database should not be deployed in the same folder as your .exe anyway, I have some ideas here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html

Comment: Ok, as I understand, every time that I'm in debugging time the original database is copied in the bin/debug directory. no? This is just a thing of control no? I suppose that when I do the installer in the end this will disappear, thanks for the Link! I will try to figure out how to manage the database with that info. The idea is that the installer put a preformated database in each install, I'm just trying to do a simple log of in/outs